# How can I remove paint smears on my vinyl siding?

Tags: paint, removal, vinyl-siding

I have some paint (latex, exterior) smears on my vinyl siding. It's set in the tiny cracks and is thoroughly cooked by the sun. I want to remove that.

I was recommended methyl hydrate, which gave me moderate success (scrubbed for a while with plain old scott towel). But it doesn't seem to be getting rid of the paint in the tiny cracks. Is there something better I could use? (I'd wash the place down with water to avoid reactions).

Comment: try a stiff paintbrush with the methyl hydrate.  It might get into the cracks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I get paint on something like clothing I use nail polish remover. It takes time to soften the paint and remove it, but it doesn't harm the fabric.

Comment: Does this work on vinyl siding too?

Comment: The trick is to always try it in a well hidden spot first to see if it causes any damages.

Comment: Also, I remember I once removed a permanent felt marker graffiti off a metal door (painted with metal paint) with nail polish remover (no acetone). Did the job, but was a but tough on the paint.

Comment: Got slightly better success with nail polish remover than methy hydrate. Applied both with a stiff paintbrush then a very stiff floor brush. It's as if the vinyl is too porous to scrub efficiently...